# Android Expandable List View Get Selected Group Child View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, decimalformat

I would like to ask how can I get the child view from specific group in expandable list view?

[image: Expandable list view]

I have tried with getChildAt(1), but it always return the child view 1(from group view 1) (blue lines and text), when I tried getChildAt(2) it will have error saying pointing view to null reference. How can I make a loop that can detect its group 2 and get its child view? I hope you can understand my question.

For now, I can just only get the group 1 child view with getChildAt(1). I wanted to get the group 2 child view instead. I am going to do a for loop that will loop all the group and update its child view accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

This is my adapter get child view:

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_loan_list_item, null);

    final CustomEditText installmentText = (CustomEditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.installmentET);
    installmentText.setTag("amount");

    installmentText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                installmentText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                formatText(installmentText, groupPosition);
                installmentText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                installmentText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

The formattext method for just formating text during key in session, like 5000 auto change to 5,000 into currency value

[image]

In my activity, I used:

```
listView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                for(int count = 1; count < people.getLoan().size(); count++) {
                    if(hasFocus) {
                        if (count != lastGroupPos) {
                            View view = listView.getChildAt(1);
                            CustomEditText editTxt = (CustomEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.installmentET);
                            String toSplit = FormatConverterUtil.formatString(editTxt);
                            people.getLoan().get(count - 1).setAmount(toSplit.replace(",", ""));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you ever tried child and group click listeners?

Comment: Post your adapter code & where you are getting the child views

Comment: child click listener does not work with me, it does not get executed when child is clicked. Imagine i have edit text on child view, after I done editing text in group 1 edit text and I direct click group 2 edit text, I want the group 1 edit text auto format its text (I'm doing currency stuff), it works well if I click outside or any view, but when I clicked the other group edit text view, it does not auto format, that is why I need to loop all the group and get its child view and format it manually

Comment: I have variable that hold the current group clicked position so that that particular group child view won't be formatted.

Comment: added my adapter get child view class, but my main concern is at the picture 2, auto format works well when I click outside any edit text areas, just when I click other edit texts, it won't auto format, so I am doing that I can manually loop through all group child view and check the last groupPosition(so that that edit text won auto format) while the rest get updated